# (Julia) Algebra of Graphics dashed/dotted option for linear() layer

Tags: plot, julia

I apply the linear() layer to some dataset. It is displayed as some solid line. How is it possible to change that line to dashed or dotted?  I can't seem to find an attribute or option that does that.

Currently have:

```
using DataFrames
using AlgebraOfGraphics
using CairoMakie

linearDataFrame =DataFrame(a = 1:10, b= 0.1*(1:10));

mainGraphData = data(linearDataFrame)*mapping(:1 ,:2);
graphLayers = linear();

plotMainGraph = mainGraphData*graphLayers;

returnPlot = draw(plotMainGraph)
```

Comment: Could you post a small working example of how the graphing is done by you now, including the data so that it can be compile to run from the example? It would make it simpler to then show how a dashed line would be added.

Comment: @Bill I added a sample above. Forgot to ping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an implicit layer (visual) that sort of gets added with no arguments when you call `linear()`. If you multiply your current plot by visual(Lines) it won't change anything, but adding a `linestyle` kwarg to visual will do what you want.

```
using DataFrames
using AlgebraOfGraphics
using CairoMakie

linearDataFrame =DataFrame(a = 1:10, b= 0.1*(1:10));

mainGraphData = data(linearDataFrame) * mapping(:1 ,:2) * visual(Lines; linestyle = :dash)
graphLayers = linear();

plotMainGraph = mainGraphData*graphLayers;

returnPlot = draw(plotMainGraph)
```

Another option if you're used to ggplot syntax:

```
using TidierPlots
using DataFrames

linearDataFrame =DataFrame(a = 1:10, b= 0.1*(1:10))

@ggplot(data = linearDataFrame) + 
  @geom_line(aes(x = a, y = b), linetype = "-")
```